# PYTHON- Programa que imprime no ecrã todos os números divisíveis por 7 mas que não são múltiplos de 5, entre 3000 e 3200 (inclusive)

Tags: python-3.x

Olá,  
Estou a fazer o seguinte programa:  
O programa deve imprimir no ecrã todos os números divisíveis por 7, mas que não sejam múltiplos de 5, entre 3000 e 3200 (inclusive).

Acontece que ja fiz o código, mas este não está a funcionar da melhor forma e, não estou a conseguir resolver.

```
print("="*25)
print("Números divisíveis por 7")
print("="*25)
# modifique as 2 proximas variaveis para testar o programa
numeroDe = 3000;
numeroAte = 3200;

pares = 0;
impares = 0;
divPorSete = 0;

while (numeroDe <= numeroAte):
    if numeroDe % 2 == 0:
        pares += 1;
    else:
        impares += 1;

    if numeroDe % 7 == 0:
        divPorSete += 1;

    numeroDe += 1;

print ("Resumo de divisiveis entre ", numeroDe, " e ", numeroAte)
print ("\t- Números pares: ", pares)
print ("\t- Números impares: ", impares)
print ("\t- Números divisiveis por 7: ", divPorSete)
```

[Experimente o código online](https://repl.it/@jpfernandes/KookyVengefulVendors)

Peço a vossa ajuda.

Comment: Já tentaste alguma coisa? Coloca esse código que tens pff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Está a fazer muitas coisas escusadas (e que nem percebo bem porquê), podes usar o modulo para ver se o resto da divisão de `i` por 7 é 0, e se o resto da divisão de `i` por 5 é diferente de 0.

Podes fazer simplesmente:

```
for i in range(3000, 3201): # percorrer todos os nums entre 3000 e 3200 (inclusive)
    if(i%7 == 0 and i%5 != 0): # modulo para ver se e multiplo de 7 e nao de 5
        print(i) # imprimir num
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/repls/MintcreamAttractiveRedundancy)

Se quiseres manter o ciclo while:

```
num_currente = 3000;
numeroAte = 3200;
while num_currente <= numeroAte:
    if(num_currente%7 == 0 and num_currente%5 != 0): # modulo para ver se e multiplo de 7 e nao de 5
        print(num_currente) # imprimir num
    num_currente += 1
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/repls/LatestGiantFunction)

Fora isto, reparei que estás a querer saber também quantos números pares/impares é que tens nesse intervalo, podes calcular isso sem ter que 
 adicionar nada dentro do ciclo:

```
...
dif = numeroAte - numeroDe
pares = dif//2
impares = pares
if(dif%2 != 0):
    impares += 1
```

[DEMOSNTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/repls/SquigglyExperiencedCable)

Comment: Era o ciclo range que eu queria!! E não me lembrava!  Muito obrigado!

Comment: @JoaoPeixotoFernandes, boa, nota que com o while dá na mesma. Bom encontrar um compatriota aqui. Boa sorte

Comment: eu sei que dá, mas queria mesmo com o range, e não estava a conseguir fazer.

Answer (score 1):

Qual o problema exatamente? Por que o seu código não está funcionando da melhor forma?

Alterei um pouco o seu código. Primeiro faltou copiar o valor da variável numeroDe, uma vez que ela era impressa no final para dizer de onde começou. Como você estava iterando a mesma variável que usaria para imprimir, o valor no final aparecia diferente.

E coloquei a condição de ser divisível por 7 mas não ser múltiplo de 5. Antes só tinha a condição de ser divisível por 7. O que diminuiu o valor de 29 para 23.

```
print("="*25)
print("Números divisíveis por 7")
print("="*25)
# modifique as 2 proximas variaveis para testar o programa
numeroDe = 3000;
copiaNumeroDe = 3000;

numeroAte = 3200;

pares = 0;
impares = 0;
divPorSete = 0;

while (numeroDe <= numeroAte):
    test = numeroDe

    if test % 2 == 0:
        pares += 1;
    else:
        impares += 1;

    if ((test % 7 == 0) and (test % 5 != 0)):
        divPorSete += 1;

    numeroDe += 1;

print ("Resumo de divisiveis entre ", copiaNumeroDe, " e ", numeroAte)
print ("\t- Números pares: ", pares)
print ("\t- Números impares: ", impares)
print ("\t- Números divisiveis por 7: ", divPorSete)
```

[Veja o código online](https://repl.it/repls/MaroonIntelligentLinks)

Answer (score 0):

```
print([i for i in range(3003,3201,7) if i%5 != 0])
```

- onde 3003 é o primeiro múltiplo de 7 nesse intervalo,
- `range(3003,32001,7)` - percorre de 7 em 7